# issues with array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

i am trying to model a car rim in blender. i modelled it with using mirror modifier and array. When creating some edge loops for sharp edges it is not appearing same on both sides of the mirror modifier instead Edge loop automatically get snaps to nearest vertex at the end of loop. I tried reducing the distance in array modifier, but its not helping. and also blender crashes when i do so. pls help. Screenshot attached for your reference[image: modelscreenshot]

[image: adding edge loops]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the mirror and array modifiers have settings to automatically merge vertices from the generated parts with the real vertices. When adding or adjusting vertices near the edge you sometimes need to disable these options for a while. Sometimes you also need to adjust the merge limit so that you don't get excessive merges happening.

[image]

Comment: yes, but like you can see in the second screenshot im unable to merge the two vertices i tried adjusting the distance also. But even if i merge that two vertices in any way there will be same problem in the next two vertices.